# Moving Google Drive file meta data into an Excel table using Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, google-drive

I have a directory on Google Drive where the contents are shown as below,
[image: Figure 1.- Google Drive screen grab showing file contents.]

I would like to move this data into an Excel table as below,
[image]

What is the best way to do this that does not involve screen grabs, OCR conversion, etc? Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Per comment below,

```
 PS C:\Users\bob> ls "G:\Other computers\My Laptop\LZ\20221225" | select Name,LastWriteTime,Length | Export.Csv "c:\videoPy\book1.csv"
```

Below are reported errors...

```
Export.Csv : The term 'Export.Csv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:84 \LZ\20221225" | select Name,LastWriteTime,Length | Export.Csv "c:\vid ...CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Export.Csv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: If you want to do it entirely within google drive, you could use an Apps script like https://spreadsheet.dev/export-list-of-files-in-google-drive-to-google-sheets-using-apps-script

Comment: Since it's a synced folder, it can be easier to use something on your local computer to list the files in that folder. For example, on windows, in powershell, you can create a csv of all the files in a folder like: `ls "c:\path\to\folder\" | select Name,LastWriteTime,Length | Export-Csv "c:\folder\book1.csv"`

Comment: Thanks. Getting closer. See attached update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got it.

```
Get-ChildItem "G:\Other computers\My Laptop\LZ\20221225" | Out-File -FilePath "c:\videoPy\book1.csv"
```